# Calling excel's function.ets from Access VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm trying to call excel's FORECAST.ETS from VBA in my access project but it seems like no matter what I do I get this error:

> "VBA Error 1004 Invalid number of arguments."

Here's what I'm doing -

```
'**********************************************
Public Sub testFCsof()

Dim testrfXL As Object

Dim testrfNowDate  As Date
Dim testrfempSQLStr As String
Dim testrfempSQLRS As DAO.Recordset

Dim testrfRecNo As Integer

Dim testrfDateARRAY() As Date
Dim testrfPointsARRAY() As Double

Dim testrfFDFCAST As Double
Dim fdtestempID As Long

On Error GoTo Err_testrfNBA

Set todaysDB = CurrentDb()

fdtestempID = 382

testrfFDFCAST = 1000000

testrfempSQLStr = "SELECT NBAFANempPER.eventTime, NBAFANempPER.FDpoints " & _
            "FROM NBAFANempPER WHERE ((NBAFANempPER.empID)= " & fdtestempID & ") ORDER BY NBAFANempPER.eventTime;"

Set testrfempSQLRS = todaysDB.OpenRecordset(testrfempSQLStr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges, dbReadOnly)

If Not (testrfempSQLRS.BOF And testrfempSQLRS.EOF) Then 'only do this if we have records

testrfempSQLRS.MoveLast

ReDim testrfDateARRAY(testrfempSQLRS.RecordCount - 1)
ReDim testrfPointsARRAY(testrfempSQLRS.RecordCount - 1)

testrfempSQLRS.MoveFirst

testrfRecNo = 0

Do While Not testrfempSQLRS.EOF

    testrfDateARRAY(testrfRecNo) = CDate(dateHeadFunk(CDate(testrfempSQLRS!eventTime)))
    testrfPointsARRAY(testrfRecNo) = CDbl(testrfempSQLRS!FDpoints)

    testrfRecNo = testrfRecNo + 1

    testrfempSQLRS.MoveNext
Loop

Set testrfXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

testrfNowDate = Now()

testrfFDFCAST = testrfXL.WorksheetFunction.Forecast.ets(Arg1:=testrfNowDate, Arg2:=testrfPointsARRAY, Arg3:=testrfDateARRAY, Arg4:=0, Arg5:=1, Arg6:=5)

Set testrfXL = Nothing

End If


Exit_testrfNBA:

Erase testrfPointsARRAY
Erase testrfDateARRAY
testrfNowDate = Empty

testrfempSQLStr = ""

If Not testrfempSQLRS Is Nothing Then
    testrfempSQLRS.Close
    Set testrfempSQLRS = Nothing
End If

Exit Sub


Err_testrfNBA:

    MsgBox "Got a sucky forecast number back.."

 generic.TestODBCErr

Resume Exit_testrfNBA

End Sub
'**********************************************
```

The arrays fill up just fine, both the same size.
I can call other Excel functions without a problem.
Can't figure out what the problem could be.  I've tried this with and without the "Arg=" tags, with and without the last three optional arguments, tried wrapping the arrays with Array(myArray), even set the Arrays to Variant.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Excel VBA, the function name is Forecast_ETS, not Forecast.ETS.

Comment: yeah its Forecast_ETS in excel vba, but should it have given an error function or procedure definition not foundor something similar

Comment: Thank you.  I plugged Forecast_ETS in but got this - "Unable to get the Forecast_ETS property of the WorksheetFunction class"..

Comment: Thank you!  I changed the name to Forecast_ETS and got this -  Unable to get the Forecast_ETS property of the WorksheetFunction class.  Is that a 'better' error than "Invalid number of arguments."?

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it. I hope someone else has the answer. Meanwhile, try to not take your frustrations out on someone who is trying to help.